# Can I add captcha for SOME websites, not whole website?

Tags: magento2, recaptcha

I'm developing a website which register customer is required to use [official reCaptcha](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/extension-install-google-recaptcha.html). But the client only want to implement reCaptcha on Website A, not Website B. The customer register form on Website B does not need to use reCaptcha. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can do so by selecting the store view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable it for only one website by following steps:

**Step 1:**
Login to admin, goto Stores -> Configuration

**Step 2:**
Then goto Customers -> Customer Configuration

**Step 3:**
Change the store or website configuration from "Store View" dropdown(at the top of left menu) to the store you want to enable captcha.

**Step 4:**
Now Select tab CAPTCHA, You can now enable it for that selected store or website by enabling "Enable CAPTCHA on Storefront"(Uncheck the 'Use system value')